# Nothing showed up from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to use ViewModel with retrofit to call responses, problem is retrofit won't call anything so nothing showed up.

Tried messing around with ViewModels where it's called

Tried generating new POJO from GSON

Put uses-permission INTERNET inside AndroidManifest

```
class MovieView(context: Context) : ViewModel() {

private val API_KEY: String = context.getString(R.string.api)
private val TAG = MovieView::class.java!!.getSimpleName()

private var resultsItem: MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>>? = null


fun getData(): LiveData<List<ResultsItem>> {
    if (resultsItem == null) {
        resultsItem = MutableLiveData()
        loadData()
    }
    return resultsItem as MutableLiveData<List<ResultsItem>>
}

fun loadData() {
    val apiInterface = ApiClient.getList().create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val responseCall = apiInterface.getMovieList(API_KEY)
    responseCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: retrofit2.Response<Response>) {
            val resultsItemList = response.body()!!.results
            resultsItem?.value = resultsItemList
            Log.d(TAG,"response")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "null")
        }
    })
}
```

}

Expected response from retrofit but none were found, null was also not there means it wasn't even executed.

EDIT :

```
class MovieFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = MovieFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: MovieView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recycler.adapter = MovieAdapter(viewModel.getData(), this.context!!)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieView::class.java)

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_fragment, container, false)
}
```

}

and

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MovieFragment movieFragment = new MovieFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayout, movieFragment);
```

Comment: Please post the code of your Activity/Fragment where you are calling `getData()`

Comment: @SandipSoni please see edited post, just posted two more classes :)

Comment: Why do you pass `LiveData` into `MovieAdapter`? It should be directly observed inside the fragment because the fragment implements `LifecycleOwner`.

Comment: how would you go about doing that? there's no method implement it right now @ErnestZamelcyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultsItem` has to be an immutable property which is observed by the Activity/Fragment and then you need to call just `loadData()`. `fun getData()` isn't even needed here.

As for the call not executing.. Are you sure nothing is really executed? Not `onResponse` neither `onFailure`? That doesn't seem possible to me. Maybe put `t.printStackTrace()` inside `onFailure` and see in the LogCat if there's this stacktrace.

Edit:

Add `commit` to your fragment transaction in `MainActivity`, like that:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.framelayout, movieFragment)
        .commit();
```

Also you should observe your `LiveData` inside fragment:

```
val adapter = MovieAdapter(this.context!!)
recycler.adapter = adapter
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieView::class.java)
viewModel.resultsItem.observe(this, Observer { adapter.update(it) })
viewModel.loadData()
```

And add a factory for your ViewModel:

```
private val factory = object: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return MovieView(this@MovieFragment.context!!) as T
    }
}

viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MovieView::class.java)
```

Comment: nope `t.printSStackTrace()` not showing anything, tried it and nothing shows. Maybe the error is while calling the fragment or when initializing the viewmodel

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.movetv.movie.entity.adapter.MovieView

Comment: Because you have a `context` in a constructor of your `ViewModel`. If you want to have a custom constructor for your viewModel then you need to also pass a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` object into `ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)` call.

Comment: no errors now, and it returns response :)) however something wrong with recyclerview as it shows nothing

Comment: Then please accept this answer as correct and ask the question about recyclerview separately. Questions on stackoverflow cannot be too broad and this one is already pretty broad.